# Retrofit Add custom object in Error callback. onFailure

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

hi i am using retrofit my callback is as follow

```
       @Override
public void onResponse(final Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {

    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
       passing this to my view

    } else {


 //      as this failed other then 200      retroCallback.onFailure(call, new Throwable(""));

    }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
    retroCallback.onFailure(call, t);
}
```

so in this how i can pass my ErrorBean instead of Throwable anyway we can pass custom model in onFailure ? as my server giving me response in some formate i want to pass that format  .. i am using retrofit 2.1.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029936/centralized-error-handling-retrofit-2 may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass Throwable and pass additional object using composition.

```
public class ErrorBean extends Throwable {
    public ErrorPayload payload = null;

    public ErrorBean(ErrorPayload payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
}
```

Then, in onError:

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
    retroCallback.onFailure(call, t);
    if (t instanceof ErrorBean) {
        // do your stuff here
        ((ErrorBean)t).payload.text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,, Retrofit's onFailure is used for handling errors like no internet connection.

To handle the error response from your Server, Error response, I mean response from Server with 4xx status code but with some JSON response for client to handle it.

Say, you are getting this error structure from Server:

```
{
    statusCode: 409,
    message: "Email address already registered"
}
```

This error will be captured in `onResponse(...)`. To handle this, create your

```
public class ErrorBean {

    private int statusCode;
    private String message;

    public ErrorBean() {
    }

    public int status() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public String message() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Create a simple ErrorHandler util:

```
public class ErrorUtils {

    public static ErrorBean parseError(Response<?> response) {
        Converter<ResponseBody, ErrorBean> converter = 
                ServiceGenerator.retrofit()
                        .responseBodyConverter(ErrorBean.class, new Annotation[0]);

        ErrorBean error;

        try {
            error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new ErrorBean();
        }

        return error;
    }
}
```

And finally,

```
...
call.enqueue(new Callback<SuccessResponse>() {  
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<SuccessResponse> call, Response<SuccessResponse> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            // use response data and do some fancy stuff :)
        } else {
            // parse the response body …
            ErrorBean error = ErrorUtils.parseError(response);
            // … and use it to show error information

            // … or just log the issue like we’re doing :)
            Log.d("error message", error.message());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
        // there is more than just a failing request (like: no internet connection)
    }
});
```

Hope you got the point..!!!

Comment: so what i have done it one common class which have extend from callback<T> so basically i want to do all calculation in  that common class and then pass . so in your way i have to do  if (response.isSuccessful()) {} in all my api call  and